# I don't understand the data type of the code that inserts the 4-byte address into the array

Tags: c

I don't understand the data type of the code that inserts the 4-byte address into the array. We're doing a buffer overflow attack, and we're inserting a four-byte address into the array from the provided source.

Notice that an error occurs if any of the `*(long *) & buf []` is missing. However, I do not understand this code. I would appreciate it if you help me.

```
*(long *) &test[0] = 0x12345678;

*(long *) &test[4] = 0x12345678;

*(long *) &test[8] = 0x12345678;
```

I don't know the meaning of `*(long *) &test[]` here.

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug and will not work reliably. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze `*(long *) &test[0] = 0x12345678;` in steps (the postfix operators have higher precedence than the prefix operators):

- `test` is either an array of bytes or a pointer to an array of bytes. The code handles both cases the same way.
- `test[0]` is an lvalue: the first element of the byte array `test` (or possibly the byte array pointed to by the pointer `test`).
- `&test[0]` is the address of this byte.
- `(long *)&test[0]` is the same address, cast as a pointer to `long`.
- `*(long *)&test[0] = 0x12345678` writes a long value to this address, overwriting `test[0]`, `test[1]`, `test[2]` and `test[3]` (on systems with 8-bit bytes and 32-bit longs).

To summarize: the code fragment writes `sizeof(long)` bytes to the beginning of the byte array `test`.

Note however a number of implicit assumptions:

- the size of `long` can be different from 4. It can even vary from one OS to another for the same processor: `sizeof(long)` is 4 bytes on 64-bit Windows but 8 bytes on 64-bit linux systems.
- the order of bytes when writing a `long` to memory may differ from one architecture to another: little endian 32-bit CPUs will write the bytes `0x78`, `0x56`, `0x34` and `0x12` in this order, while big endian CPUs will write the same bytes in the opposite order.
- there is no guarantee that `test[0]` is properly aligned for writing a `long` value to it. Intel CPUs are configured by default to accept misaligned accesses for standard integer sizes, but most CPUs cannot be configured this way and misaligned access has undefined behavior.
- the compiler may take advantage of the strict aliasing rule to optimize accesses to the `test` array. Since you are modifying via a different effective type, it may be fooled and not reload values from memory:

  ```
  char test[12] = { 0 };
  *(long *)test[0] = 0x12345678;
  if (test[0] == 0) {
      // the compiler could assume that `test[0]` is still `0`.
  }
  ```

Comment: 4th assumption: Type based aliasing optimizations are not enabled on compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation to me.
Good day.

Comment: @chqrlie It _is_ a problem in this case. You can go from any type _to_ character type, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed it is a problem. Answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

```
//an example as follows
    int test[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    //test[0]-->It'value is 0,it's type is int.
    //&test[0]-->Its value is the address of test[0],what is its type? int*.
    //* &test[0]-->how about it?Its value is 0, its type is int too.
    //*(long*)&test[0] -->Its value is 0,but its type is long.
```